# web method base 64 bytes

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am sending a base64 string from a VBScript to a webservice. This script reads the image and this path and converts it to base64. Then the script calls a webservice with this base64 parameter.

```vb
Dim sFilePath

' Load a binary file, in this case an image.
sFilePath ="C:\\images\\124.tif"

Dim inStream
' ADODB stream object used
'Set WScript = CreateObject("WSH.WScript") 

Set inStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
' open with no arguments makes the stream an empty container
inStream.Open
inStream.Type= 1
inStream.LoadFromFile(sFilePath)
Dim readBytes
readBytes = inStream.Read()

Dim DM, EL
Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
EL.DataType = "bin.base64"
' Set bytes, get encoded String
EL.NodeTypedValue = readBytes
Dim encodeBase64
encodeBase64 = EL.Text
ProcessSend strDocHandle, encodeBase64 'DocHandle is the documentid

Function ProcessSend(strDocHandle, encodeBase64) 
    MsgBox("Calling ProcessSend1")
    Dim oXMLHTTP, oXMLDoc, strEnvelope
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = GetRef("HandleStateChange")

    strEnvelope = "Documentid=" & CStr(strDocHandle) & "&SigCard=" & encodeBase64

    Call oXMLHTTP.open("POST", "http://hostetd.com/Services/cards.asmx/" & "SaveImage", False)
    Call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Call oXMLHTTP.send(strEnvelope)
End Function

Sub HandleStateChange 
    If (oXMLHTTP.readyState = 4) Then
        Dim szResponse: szResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText
        Call oXMLDoc.loadXML(szResponse)
        If (oXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
            'Call MsgBox("ERROR")
            response = oXMLHTTP.responseText & " " & oXMLDoc.parseError.reason
            'Call MsgBox(oXMLDoc.parseError.reason)
        Else
            response = oXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")(0).childNodes(0).text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Web Service:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public void SaveImage(int DocumentId, string image)
{
  byte[] readBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image); //Not working here. This is the last statement that gets executed. Nothing gets logged after this
}
```

Fiddler says Object reference is null.

Comment: The VBScript code doesn't show where you call the Web Service can we see that please?

Comment: @Lankymart: Edited

Comment: You've confirmed in Fiddler the `SigCard` contains a valid base64 encoded string?

Comment: According to the given C# webmethod, your form input name must be `image` not `SigCard`. See the request example at `/Services/cards.asmx?op=SaveImage` to confirm parameter name.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin that is likely the culprit not big on ASMX prefer ASP.Net Web API and the `[FromBody]` parameter attribute. Wasn't sure if in ADMX the parameter type just had to de-serialise to what was being passed and whether the name actually mattered.